# Multi Curl one url returns null

Tags: php, curl

So I've got different parts of an algorithm on different urls to make it faster. I've got 4 curl requests total and one of them fails sometimes. They all return something and finally in the end it gives out a result based on all the responses.

The one that fails sometimes requests customer data from external site API and when gets it inserts it to database. If the customer data is newer than 30 days it uses DB data else does a request for newer data. Returns null if there's no data or it is older than 30 days. Takes time up to 3 seconds max.

I created a multi curl class. In the beginning it does a regular curl that returns cookies and uses them with multi curl - for passing login. In the end it returns all the responses in an array.

What might be the issue here?

File that uses multi curl:

```
$multiCurl = new MY_MULTICURL_CLASS();
$multiCurl->setRequestData($data);
$multiCurl->addRequestUrl('http://sampleurl.com/');
$multiCurl->addRequestUrl('http://sampleurl.com/');
$multiCurl->addRequestUrl('http://sampleurl.com/');
$multiCurl->addRequestUrl('http://sampleurl.com/');
$responses = $multiCurl->getData();
```

MY_MULTICURL_CLASS getData method:

```
public function getData()
    {
        /* Getting login cookie */
        $returnCookies = $this->loginCookies(null, true);
        //create the multiple cURL handle
        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        // set curl resources and options
        $k = 1;
        foreach ($this->requestURLS as $url)
        {
            ${"ch".$k} = curl_init();
            curl_setopt(${"ch".$k}, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt(${"ch".$k}, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt(${"ch".$k}, CURLOPT_COOKIE, implode(';', $returnCookies));
            curl_setopt(${"ch".$k}, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt(${"ch".$k}, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
            curl_setopt(${"ch".$k}, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
            curl_setopt(${"ch".$k}, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($this->requestData));
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, ${"ch".$k});
            $k++;
        }
        $active = null;
        //execute the handles
        do
        {
             $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        }
        while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK)
        {
            if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1)
            {
                do
                {
                    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
                }
                while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            }
        }
        for($i=1; $i <= count($this->requestURLS);$i++)
        {
            $content = curl_multi_getcontent(${"ch".$i});
            $response[] = json_decode($content, true);
            //close the handles
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, ${"ch".$i});
        }
        curl_multi_close($mh);
        return $response;
    }
```